# Can you create a "seconds" timer in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Test Timer Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YbbsFRUU9C5PC0Jsigs7gMQLcRWdwoEt9igU5vxgw8c/edit?usp=sharing)

My understanding is that it isn't possible due to the limitations of `Spreadsheet Settings > Calculations`.  I have successfully implemented `Days`, `Hours`, and `Minutes` into my timer - but it would be cool to have the `Seconds` as well.

[image: Current Timer]

Formulae:

- =IFERROR(DAY(AH9-NOW()),0)
- =IFERROR(HOUR(AH9-NOW()),0)
- =IFERROR(MINUTE(AH9-NOW()),0)

*`AH9` refers to the grey date cell in the timer

The `Seconds` timer isn't essential, more aesthetic - but I was interested to see if it was possible or not.

Comment: What is it that you are going to time?

Comment: Just a countdown timer to a specified Date/Time - question edited with more detail

Comment: have you tried SECOND? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093054?hl=en

Comment: I have, but it doesn't refresh and update every second - only on change and every minute.  I don't know of a way to get it to refresh that specific cell any faster.

Comment: Could you please share a sample piece of your code where you do the timer with minutes and hours? Also, do you want it to refresh every time the user refresh the sheet (in this case it is definitely possible)? Have you considered using this timer with an add on (altough you would probably be encountering the same issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Mateo - I've added a link to the spreadsheet at the top of the question.  I want it to refresh every second - hence the seconds timer.  Currently have the spreadsheet set to update every minute.  Limitations with Google Sheets doesn't seem to allow you to set the spreadsheet to update every hour, and then have a few cells that update more frequently (every minute or second).

Answer (score 1):

I have added some script into your workbook which does run a seconds timer.

The script that I have added is subject to the limitations of Apps Script run time but I have added various triggers in which should hopefully fire up the script once it has ended.  I have also added a button to start the script as well but you may want to delete this out?

The script on its own will run for 4-5 mins, the triggers should set this so that there is only a small interval when the seconds won't be working.

Please note that to make this script run it needs to add a date into a cell - if you set A1 to colour black, you will see this there.  The script will add this in if you delete it out so no real need to worry about leaving it there etc.

If you need to change the cell where this is, just change the global variable in the apps script project.

Hope this helps!!

---

The script I used was as below.  The triggers that I used were a time driven trigger based on a minute timer then set it to every minute.  As each function of the script works for 15 seconds, this creates a loop for a minute, which is triggered every minute.

I did play around but unfortunately I couldn't get the maths right to make it run for any longer :)...

```js
var CELL_RANGE = 'A1'

function updateCell() {
  for (i=0; i<15; i++){
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    var date = new Date();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(CELL_RANGE).setValue(date);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    updateCell1()
  } 
}

function updateCell1() {
  for (i=0; i<15; i++){
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    var date = new Date();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(CELL_RANGE).setValue(date);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    updateCell2()
  } 
}

function updateCell2() {
  for (i=0; i<15; i++){
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    var date = new Date();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(CELL_RANGE).setValue(date);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    updateCell3()
  } 
}

function updateCell3() {
  for (i=0; i<15; i++){
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
    var date = new Date();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(CELL_RANGE).setValue(date);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    updateCell()
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add to your answer the code you have used to make this possible and the installable triggers you have used so that anyone reaching this question can easily see how to solve this issue? Thanks a lot in advanced !

Comment: I did see it working, but I have bee busy with stuff.  Now that I've come back to it, it's not working any more.  Are you able to have a quick look at it please @Gav?

Comment: @Aaron Irvine - sorry, I deleted the triggers out to try something else but have added them back in now.  The triggers were a minute timer on 'every minute' and an on open trigger.

Comment: Oh that's cool mate.  I've been rather distracted and hadn't really sat down and had a look at your work.  Thanks for having a crack at it!  I'll give it a look over soon.  Will it impact the total allowable script time the servers allow each day?  I already have a bajillion scripts and functions running in my big spreadsheet!

Comment: I guess it would in that case.... you could just use an installable trigger on open so that when someone opens the sheet it will run for the max run time (4-5 mins)